# What is the recommended OAuth Flow for thick clients (with no browser)?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, thick-client

I want to integrate OAuth with a thick client which doesn't have browser support. I have read Okta documentation & it says Device Code flow is the recommended one. However, few online forums (including ChatGPT) say to use Authorisation Code flow with PKCE.

Could you please guide which one is better & why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean a desktop app, then the standard option is to use a native apps solution, as defined in [RFC8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252), which runs a code flow + PKCE.

This involves spinning up a system browser to do the login, so that the application never gains access to the user's credentials. The app then receives the response by listening on a local URL for the browser response. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/final-desktop-sample-overview/) shows what this might look like, though the user experience is not perfect.

The [device flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8628) is instead used in scenarios where a device with limited user input capabilities needs to get tokens and call an API. An example might be a smart TV, that starts the flow, presents a code and authentication URL to the user, then polls the authorization server. The user then authenticates using a mobile app or desktop computer. That is probably not the behaviour you want though.